# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user_id' - Still not logging in

Tags: android, google-app-engine

so im using the web server google app engine, and i received this auth error

the thing is that i use :

```
class Tester(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            nickname = user.nickname() + user.user_id()
            logout_url = users.create_logout_url('/test')
            greeting = \
                'Welcome, {}! (<a href="{}">sign out</a>)'.format(nickname,
                    logout_url)
        else:
            login_url = users.create_login_url('/test')
            greeting = '<a href="{}">Sign in</a>'.format(login_url)

        self.response.write('<html><body>{}</body></html>'.format(greeting))
```

I call it from my app but i'm getting the "sign in"
so im using the html i received from the server in the app like that :

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);

browser.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, getIntent().getStringExtra("text"), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

a browser is opening, im signing in, and then i see it in the browser
but in my app the registration doesn;t occur since i'm getting the same error.

any ideas?

Trace:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user_id'
at action (/base/data/home/apps/s~dddd-dogi-1234/1.395664440632566070/main.py:2276)
at get (/base/data/home/apps/s~dddd-dogi-1234/1.395664440632566070/main.py:2295)
at post (/base/data/home/apps/s~dddd-dogi-1234/1.395664440632566070/main.py:2292)
at dispatch (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py:570)
at dispatch (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py:572)
at __call__ (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py:1102)
at default_dispatcher (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py:1278)
at __call__ (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py:1529)
at __call__ (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py:1535)
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: i did it  Dan Cornilescu

Comment: That's not from the code you posted, there is no `.email` in that snippet...

Comment: Check in your `def post(self):` function.  When a query returns `None` (no entity found), you cannot get its `.email` property.  Your query in the post function is not returning any entity, so you need to wrap that .email part in an if/then.

Comment: im sorry, its another thing user.email(), but i've changed to right one